# jquery get dynamic php value of hidden input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of a hidden input set with php and use it for a jquery progressbar widget, but this code doesn't run. Could you help me?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bar").progressbar({
        value: ("#profile_completed").val(); //by id
    });
});
```

Comment: check the console, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Maybe "$ is not a function" ?

Comment: missing "$" before "("#profile_completed").val()" ?

Comment: thanks for your help, I have just inserted $ but it doesn't run..this is the complete code with php
http://pastebin.com/Ka8jTRdf

Comment: Did you check the console, as @Yasky said ?

Comment: Did you include jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: yes, already included the CDN..console shows nothing..
http://pastebin.com/r5HhDAkT

Comment: You'll need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bar").progressbar({
        value: $("#profile_completed").val(); //by id
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code below...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bar").progressbar({
        value: ("#profile_completed").val(); //by id
    });
});
```

...is the only point in your script from which there's an error, then...

The data passed into the `progressbar()` function is malformed; you would have a syntax error because of the `;` after `.val()`

Remove the semi-colon after `.val()` and your code should run.

The [JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) would give you a well rounded idea on how to pass data in JSON format into functions.

Also, using the developer tools of any recent browser could give you hints on what the errors lurking in your code may be. It helps!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. After several improvements, the correct code is:

```
$(function() {
  var str = parseInt($('#profile_completed').text());
$( "#bar" ).progressbar({
  value: str
});
```

});

It was necessary to convert with jquery the string value contained into the hidden div. Thks again